# Closest function not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am making a select list.

Now I want to show the options in select list with class "new" according to change in option in list with class old".

Like, when the option 1 is selected, 3,4,5 are visible and when the option 2 is selected, 6,7,8 are visible.

Also, I want to control the options in corresponding row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".new").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $('.new option[value="select"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="1"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="2"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="3"]').show();
  $(function() {
    $(".old").change(function() {
      var a = $(this).val();
      if (a == 2) {
        $(".new").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
        $('$(this).closest('tr').find('.new') option[value="select"]').show();
        $('$(this).closest('tr').find('.new') option[value="4"]').show();
        $('$(this).closest('tr').find('.new') option[value="5"]').show();
        $('$(this).closest('tr').find('.new') option[value="6"]').show();
      };
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="old">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="new">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="old">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="new">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('$(this).closest('tr ').find('.new ') option[value="select"]').show();` - of course this doesn’t work, because you’re messing up the quotes. This isn’t even valid JavaScript, you should get syntax errors shown in browser console.

Comment: You messed up the quotes, you need double-inner or change the outer ones to double.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in `jQuery` statement

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".new").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.new option[value="select"]').show();
    $('.new option[value="1"]').show();
    $('.new option[value="2"]').show();
    $('.new option[value="3"]').show();
    $(function () {
        $(".old").change(function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            if (a == 2) {
                $(".new").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.new option[value="select"]').show();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.new option[value="4"]').show();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.new option[value="5"]').show();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.new option[value="6"]').show();
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the invalid quotes around your jQuery calls.

Also, `$(function(){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`, so you do not need a ready function twice.

```js
$(function() {
  // Hide all children for all 'new' combos.
  $('.new').children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  
  // Show only first three 'new' items (if available).
  $('.new option[value="select"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="1"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="2"]').show();
  $('.new option[value="3"]').show();

  $('.old').change(function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a == 2) {
      // Hide all children for all 'new' combos.
      $('.new').children('option:gt(0)').hide();
      
      // Show only the 'new' items for the current row.
      let $rowNew = $(this).closest('tr').find('.new');
      $rowNew.find('option[value="select"]').show();
      $rowNew.find('option[value="4"]').show();
      $rowNew.find('option[value="5"]').show();
      $rowNew.find('option[value="6"]').show();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="old">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="new">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="old">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="new">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```